# SSIS Rearrange Full Name In Same Column

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression

I have an excel file to load into my database, I'd like to rearrange the name field to this

```html
FIRSTNAME M LASTNAME
```

instead of the format it's in now which is

```html
LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME M.
```

to keep it consistent with a previous load I have loaded into my database.  Is it possible to do this somehow and put it into the same column?  I've searched, and have only found that people have been wanting to split them into multiple columns.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best approach is separated columns for each .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a derived column that nests and concatenates a bunch of substrings.  I don't have an example handy, but the substring function is well documented and it should just be a matter of spending the time required to figure it out.

Another option would be to handle this in a script transformation, if you're more comfortable with string manipulation in a .net language.

Comment: Thanks, I've had previous experience with splitting a full name in a single column into multiple columns, but I'm not familiar with splitting then rearranging then actually putting into the same column.

Comment: If you can split the string, then instead of saying substring A goes to Column A, substring B to ColumnB, etc, you would just concatenate them into one column like: `substring A + " " + substring B + " " + substring C`.

Comment: Hmm..so you're saying create a new column for each field (first, middle, last), then a final column (full) where I concatenate all the columns?

Comment: No.  I am saying add One new column using One big expression that does:  `{substring for first name} + " " + {substring for middle initial} + " " {substring for last name}`

Comment: OHH, gotcha.  That makes  more sense. Thanks so much for the help!!